# browser automation with PhantomJS and Firefox, support of the different browsers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, browser-automation

Why the code works with webdriver.Firefox but do not work with webdriver.PhantomJS ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # why not?
# driver.set_window_size(1400, 1050)

# driver = webdriver.Firefox() # Firefox 45, works correctly

driver.get("https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/public/lgc-register")
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[4].click() # status
# show the needed elements for the next action,
# enter(open the door) to the div.ms-drop area
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ms-drop')[4].find_element_by_css_selector('ul>li:nth-child(12)').click()  # registered
driver.find_element_by_id('search-submit').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # search

driver.save_screenshot('lgc1.png')
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work with phantomjs?? Is there any exception?? And why are you not using `driver.find_element_by_id('search-submit').click()` instead of `driver.find_element_by_id('search-submit').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` ..??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur 
in Phantomjs it stops on div.ms-drop, without any exceptions,
but in Firefox, I get the html table with needed data.

After that phantomjs should click on checkbox and on a search button.

Comment: And why are you using `send_keys(Keys.RET‌​URN)`???

Comment: yes you are right,
it works on Firefox in both cases.

Comment: Ok but I would suggest you try using `.click()` in both firefox as well as phantomjs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `.click()` for click purpose instead of `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` as below :

```
driver.find_element_by_id('search-submit').click()
```

Comment: thanks, after that I get empty table in Phantomjs.

and after

import time
time.sleep(3)

I get needed data

Comment: For best way I would suggest you try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until table present after click instead of `time.sleep`...:)

Comment: I have tried to use a **WebDriverWait** and **implicitly_wait** before,
but it do not works here and previously:
...
`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`
`time.sleep(3) # > 2, works`
`# driver.implicitly_wait(30) # > 30, do not works`
`# WebDriverWait(driver, 30) # > 30, do not works`

Comment: WebDriverWait uses on element with certain conditions?? Only creating object is not enough..you need to provide certain conditions for element...:)

Comment: For more information have a look here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html..

Comment: okay, I'll try the conditions again, 
but I used the example from 
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
for the Implicit Waits.

Comment: thanks, I use already this site for a few months as a main guidance.

Comment: at last **WebDriverWait** become working via:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))`

Comment: Yeah now you have got it. this is the correct way...:)